# How to check if div exists with jQuery AFTER other jQuery functions run and create html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that when clicks adds new html to the document. How can I check if there is a specific element within the new html?

I tried

```
  $(document).on('click', '#add-html-code', function() {

     if ($('#something').length > 0) { alert('yes'); }
 });
```

To test it, but nothing happens. 
Thanks

EDIT: solved.

Comment: You haven't shown where the HTML content is added relative to this check for the existence of `#something`.

Comment: your code seem to work for me, but not sure if you have the same html structure. http://jsfiddle.net/wgCV4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('#element-to-which-the-html-was-added')
    .find('#element-you-are-looking-for').length) {
  alert('yes');
}
```